# terminate a member account in my aws organizations?(not the root account)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

I want to terminate my member account(child account) in AWS organizations.

Will I still be charged for resources, that weren't manually deleted, owned by this account? or it will remove all resources? for example instances, backup, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice when closing an AWS account is to delete first all the resources because AWS might not automatically terminate all the active resources and will incur in additional cost.

Delete on-demand resources should not be a problem but any other types (e.g Reserved Instances, Saving Plans) will be still charged until the plan term ends.

The same concept apply to accounts that belongs to an Organization.

---

Reference:

[Terminate resources on account closure](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/terminate-resources-account-closure/)

[Closed account billing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/closed-account-bill/)